# Creating a new accumulative column in a data frame based on existing columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

I created this topic: Calculating new column in a data frame based on existing columns a while ago. I am looking now for something similar with a little distinction. I, again, have this dataset..

```
df=tibble(article=rep("article one",5), 
week=c(1,2,3,4,5), 
sales=20, 
purchase=c(5,0,5,5,0), 
stock=c(50))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  article      week sales purchase stock
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 article one     1    20        5    50
2 article one     2    20        0    50
3 article one     3    20        5    50
4 article one     4    20        5    50
5 article one     5    20        0    50
```

.. wherenmy desired outcome would look like the following:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  article      week sales purchase stock stock_over_time
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
1 article one     1    20        5    50              50
2 article one     2    20        0    50              30
3 article one     3    20        5    50              15
4 article one     4    20        5    50               0
5 article one     5    20        0    50              -5
```

so stock_over_time is calculated as follows, where whenever `stock_over_time` would go beneath `0`, sales is subtracted, but only a ratio of sales (here .25 of sales).

```
50 - 20 + 0 = 30
30 - 20 + 5 = 15
15 - 20 + 5 = 0
0 - (20 * 1/4) + 0 = -5
```

Comment: What would you like to happen after this, e.g. in "row 6"? Let's say it's like row 5 with another 20 in sales, reduced to 5 after the .25 reduction. Should `stock_over_time` become -5 or -10?

Comment: `stock_over_time` would then become -10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `cumsum` with `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(article) %>%
  mutate(stock_over_time =  lag(stock + cumsum(lead(purchase) - sales),
       default = first(stock)),
     stock_over_time = case_when(stock_over_time < 0 
           ~ 0 - (sales * 1/4) + purchase, TRUE ~ stock_over_time)) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#  article      week sales purchase stock stock_over_time
#  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
#1 article one     1    20        5    50              50
#2 article one     2    20        0    50              30
#3 article one     3    20        5    50              15
#4 article one     4    20        5    50               0
#5 article one     5    20        0    50              -5
```

---

As @JonSpring mentioned, it may be recursive action, in that case we can create a function to do this

```
f1 <- function(dat) {
   dat$stock_over_time <- NA_real_
   dat$stock_over_time[1] <- dat$stock[1]
   for(i in 2:nrow(dat)) {
         
      dat$stock_over_time[i] <- dat$stock_over_time[i-1] - 
                      dat$sales[i] + dat$purchase[i]
         if(dat$stock_over_time[i] < 0 ) {
             dat$stock_over_time[i] <- dat$stock_over_time[i-1] - 
                 (dat$sales[i]* 1/4) + dat$purchase[i]
          }  
   }
   return(dat)
 }


unsplit(lapply(split(df, df$article), f1), df$article)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#  article      week sales purchase stock stock_over_time
#  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
#1 article one     1    20        5    50              50
#2 article one     2    20        0    50              30
#3 article one     3    20        5    50              15
#4 article one     4    20        5    50               0
#5 article one     5    20        0    50              -5
```

---

or can use `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
f1 <- function(x, y, z) {
         tmp <- x - y + z
         if(tmp < 0) {
            tmp <- x - (y* 1/4) + z
            }
         
         return(tmp)
         }

}


df %>% 
  group_by(article) %>%
  mutate(stock_over_time = accumulate2(sales, 
     lead(purchase, default = last(purchase)), f1, .init = first(stock)) %>%
                    flatten_dbl() %>%
                    head(-1)) %>%
  ungroup
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#  article      week sales purchase stock stock_over_time
#  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>
#1 article one     1    20        5    50              50
#2 article one     2    20        0    50              30
#3 article one     3    20        5    50              15
#4 article one     4    20        5    50               0
#5 article one     5    20        0    50              -5
```

Comment: Does this logic work for further rows, though? I don't think "row 6" would see the modified `stock_over_time` that was calculated in row 5. I think a loop or something like `purrr::accumulate` is needed, because the sales in each row depend on the state of stock at that moment.

Comment: @JonSpring I was also thinking in the `accumulate` way.  With the current example, I thought, the cumsum should do the job

Comment: @JonSpring I guess the update should fix the issue you mentioned

Comment: the update definitely is doing the job, thank you very much! I however prefer tidy approaches (e.g. accumulate), so I will try to adapt the function to accumulate.

Comment: @lucaskr it is possible with `accumulate`, but I thought a `for` loop would be more easier and readable

Comment: @akrun would u mind share a idee to get this to work? iam still to unfamiliar with the `purrr` package

Comment: @lucaskr One thing I am not clear is whether the values in 'stock' or 'sales' are same or is it different for different rows of same 'article'.  If I have to use `accumulate`, that needs to be clarified

Comment: @akrun values for sales and stock are same for all coming rows

Comment: @lucaskr i updated the solution with accumulate